# Reading AuthorizationSection from web.config provides incorrect values

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Edit #2: config.FilePath is showing that it's looking at a different file than what I'm expecting: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config". I was expecting it to use the web.config in my project. Need to figure out why that's happening.

I have a method in my web API where I'm trying to read the values from the authorization section in my web.config. Based on what I've found, this should work:

```
    public AuthorizationSetting GetAuthorizationSettings()
    {
        var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
        var section = config.GetSection("system.web/authorization") as AuthorizationSection;

        foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in section.Rules)
        {
            if (rule.Action.ToString().ToLower() == "allow")
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(rule);
            }
        }

        return new AuthorizationSetting();
    }
```

And this is the section of the web.config that contains the authorization info:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="role1,role2,role3"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

You can see that there is one allow and one deny. When I run the code, it appears that there is only one rule. Shouldn't there be two since there is an allow and a deny? And the one rule looks to have an Action of Allow and "*" for Users. That's not what's in the web.config. What am I missing here?

[image]

** Edit **
I've considered the possibility that it's reading a different web.config file. But there is only one other web.config file in the solution (under Views). I also changed it to have the same authorization section, but I still get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already figured out using `Null` in for the `path` parameter of `OpenWebConfiguration` loads the server root web.config in

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\
```

the documentation says:

`The virtual path to the configuration file. If null, the root Web.config file is opened.`

but one could assume it would be the root web config of the site, not the server. Anyway, try using:

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

Comment: That did it. Not very intuitive. Thank you.